# need replace document.getElementsByTagName to document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found this code on the web:

```
function getIPs(callback){
var ip_dups = {};
var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
    || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
    || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
if(!RTCPeerConnection){
    var win = iframe.contentWindow;
    RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
        || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
        || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
}
var mediaConstraints = {
    optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
};
var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);
function handleCandidate(candidate){
    var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
    var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];
    if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
        callback(ip_addr);
    ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
}
pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){
    //skip non-candidate events
    if(ice.candidate)
        handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
};
pc.createDataChannel("");
pc.createOffer(function(result){
    pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});
}, function(){});
setTimeout(function(){
    var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');
    lines.forEach(function(line){
        if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
            handleCandidate(line);
    });
}, 1000);
}
//insert IP addresses into the page
getIPs(function(ip){
  var localip = document.createElement("span");
  localip.textContent = ip;
  //local IPs
  if (ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/))
    document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[1].appendChild(localip);
});
```

Now I need to change `document.getElementsByTagName` to `document.getElementsById`, remove the `document.createElement("span")` , and have only the result, because I need to print it in two places.

For example:

```
document.getElementById("local-ip").innerHTML = ip
<div id="local-ip"></div>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("local-ip2").value = ip
<input type="text" id="local-ip2" /> //here as value
```

I spent a lot of time on it, without success...

Comment: You can use `document.getElementById("local-ip").appendChild(localip);`, but you'll need to change one of your elements' ID, because IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: yes, it works, but i need to remove the span element that i don't need...plus, have the same value in an input field

Comment: I don't see any span element in the HTML provided. You've got an answer for the answerable part of your question. If you have other questions, please provide a [mcve] in a new question, which replicates the issue.

Comment: var localip = document.createElement("span"); <-- this is the span element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question. If a `span` is not required you can happily avoid creating it.

```
function parse() {
    var ip = document.getElementById('userIP').value;
    if (ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/)) {
        document.getElementById("local-ip2").value = ip;
        document.getElementById("local-ip").innerHTML = ip;
    }
};
```

```
<input type="text" id="userIP" value="192.168.1.1" />
<button onclick="parse()">Parse</button>
```

This post is just clarifying things that you might have overlooked.

Comment: i have to insert an ip, into text field! Look now the entired code... i need to edit only the final part

Comment: @Devilix that's a big edit. But this code still holds. You can set it in any place you want. I added userIP text box with default value to capture user input. ip is not an html element anymore. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/2194ft05/

Comment: all that code, print a local ip user, maybe you don't understand everything... check this https://jsfiddle.net/2194ft05/1/

Comment: Thanks! Now it work! but for input field? look here! https://jsfiddle.net/2194ft05/4/

Comment: No probs.. just add the example code you provided in the question. `document.getElementById("local-ip2").value = ip`

Comment: You might want to add braces for you if statement {} https://jsfiddle.net/2194ft05/5/

Comment: Damn! Perfect! You save my day! :D
Thanks a lot bro!!! Many many thanks!

Comment: @Devilix No probs. To be fair there was nothing wrong in your code. I think you just started on js. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your function had if () with no following {} braces, which means that only the statement following the if () is executed, so making the code less readable.

I've put the  creation, text content = ip, appendChild all together, so it should be straight forward to see what's happening.

Just needs to pass the regExp.

```js
getIPs = function() {

var ip = document.getElementById('local-ip2').value;
  
//local IPs

if ( ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/) ) {
      //document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[1].appendChild(localip);
      var localip = document.createElement("span");  
          localip.textContent = ip;
          document.getElementById('local-ip').appendChild(localip);
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="local-ip"></div>
<input type="text" id="local-ip2" /> //here as value
<button onclick="getIPs()">Get IP</button>
```

Comment: yes, but in my question i have asked also to remove appendChild (span element) that i don't need... can you update your answer?